# tmux "last-session" binding

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

How could I bind to last (most recent) session? The obvious `last-session` leads to an "unknown command" error.

```
bind-key z last-session
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't know about how to bind to the <kbd>Eject</kbd> key (it's too far from the home keys anyway!) but this will do the trick:

```
bind-key -n z switch-client -l
```

Comment: Doesn't this bind `z` to this action even without the tmux prefix? I'd prefer `bind-key z switch-client -l` so it's easier to type `z` into a terminal when it's needed.

Comment: Do not use -n lol it'll be very bad each time you have to type `z` into the terminal.

Answer (score 9):

In recent versions of tmux (e.g. 2.6) the key `Prefix`-`L` is already bound to the command `switch-client -l` which as **user47464** pointed out is probably what you want.

You can check your bindings with `Prefix`-`?`:

```
...
bind-key    -T prefix       L                 switch-client -l
...
```